# Inline condition produces the wrong result

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add the '0' to the number which is less than 10. for that i trying to write a inline code like this. ( i don't require filter here, since this is for visual purpose not required to change object. )

```
 <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="d in Num">{{d < 10 ? d= '0'+d : d}}</li>
 </ul>
```

But getting result like this:

```
000000000001
000000000002
000000000003
000000000004
000000000005
000000000006
000000000007
000000000008
000000000009
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

How to fix this? or what is wrong here?

[Live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2xfLW5CPks9Y31YKYMV?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change it like

```
 <li ng-repeat="d in Num">{{d < 10 ?  '0'+d : d}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are trying to get?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.Num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="d in Num">{{d < 10 ?  '0'+d : d}}</li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
```

Happy Helping!